# Cannot run JD-GUI with 64-bit shared libraries, needs 32-bit libraries

Tags: fedora, yum, libraries, 64bit, gtk

I was trying to use [JD-GUI](http://jd.benow.ca/), a free Java decompiler program, on my Fedora 20 laptop today, but I was running into an error when trying to execute the program.

```
$ '/home/jflory/Downloads/jd-gui-0.3.5.linux.i686/jd-gui' 
/home/jflory/Downloads/jd-gui-0.3.5.linux.i686/jd-gui: error while loading shared libraries: libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

After receiving this error, I went to find out what package provides this library.

```
$ sudo yum whatprovides libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0
gtk2-2.24.22-2.fc20.i686 : The GIMP ToolKit (GTK+), a library for creating GUIs for X
Repo        : fedora
Matched from:
Provides    : libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0

gtk2-2.24.24-2.fc20.i686 : The GIMP ToolKit (GTK+), a library for creating GUIs for X
Repo        : updates
Matched from:
Provides    : libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0
```

I noticed it was the 32-bit architecture for this package. I have a 64-bit computer and I am using the 64-bit version of Fedora 20. I tried to install the 32-bit version of `gtk2`.

```
$ sudo yum install gtk2.i686
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package gtk2.i686 0:2.24.24-2.fc20 will be installed
[snip]
--> Running transaction check
[snip]
--> Finished Dependency Resolution

Error:  Multilib version problems found. This often means that the root
       cause is something else and multilib version checking is just
       pointing out that there is a problem. Eg.:

     1. You have an upgrade for cairo which is missing some
        dependency that another package requires. Yum is trying to
        solve this by installing an older version of cairo of the
        different architecture. If you exclude the bad architecture
        yum will tell you what the root cause is (which package
        requires what). You can try redoing the upgrade with
        --exclude cairo.otherarch ... this should give you an error
        message showing the root cause of the problem.

     2. You have multiple architectures of cairo installed, but
        yum can only see an upgrade for one of those architectures.
        If you don't want/need both architectures anymore then you
        can remove the one with the missing update and everything
        will work.

     3. You have duplicate versions of cairo installed already.
        You can use "yum check" to get yum show these errors.

   ...you can also use --setopt=protected_multilib=false to remove
   this checking, however this is almost never the correct thing to
   do as something else is very likely to go wrong (often causing
   much more problems).

   Protected multilib versions: cairo-1.12.16-1.4.i686 != cairo-1.13.1-0.1.git337ab1f.fc20.x86_64
```

So it seems that installing the 32-bit architecture package for `gtk2` has numerous other implications. I was searching around and found [this thread](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-software-2/error-while-loading-shared-libraries-libgtk-x11-2-0-so-0-a-921435/) on the LinuxQuestions.org, and apparently his solution was running `yum update` and then doing `yum install gtk2.i686`. However, that is not working for me.

My laptop is fully updated with all packages in Fedora's repositories. My Linux kernel is `3.16.3-200.fc20.x86_64`.

Ultimately, how can I get JD-GUI to work with my machine without removing the 64-bit libraries? Is there a workaround for compatibility of the 64-bit / 32-bit packages?

Comment: Are you able to run and/or compile *any* 32-bit applications?

Comment: @peterph: I'm unsure of compiling. I'm fairly certain I've used 32-bit programs in the past, but... it's been so long I can't remember. Also, I don't know if I have any other 32-bit programs readily available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi to resolve similar issue it helped me to install .x64 version first.

It seems like yum is complaining about different version of .x64 package installed and .i686 you want to install.

So

```
sudo yum install gtk2.x86_64

sudo yum install gtk2.i686
```

worked for me

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me was

```
rpm --erase --nodeps cairo
```

which removes the `cairo` package without checking any dependencies that might be violated by such an action, followed by

```
yum install cairo
```

which installs cairo from the configured package repositories

Comment: Might there be any unexpected side effects of running these commands? I'm newish to Linux and I'm not too familiar with all the things the `rpm` command can do. I'm not currently at my Fedora machine, but I will try this when I get the opportunity.

Comment: @doomsdy290 next time please do provide at least basic explanation of any commands you suggest. This is so that our site doesn't turn into a book of spells from which one randomly picks an incantation and hopes for the best. Rather that that, we strive to explain and help to understand. You might also consider giving a bit more background than *"what worked for me was"* - it's not entirely clear whether you were in the same (or similar) situation or not. Thanks.